# 2007 VW Jetta Wolfsburg Edition

Tags: vibration

My car seems to wobble when I accelerate and continues at slow speeds. It seems to go away at greater speeds. I have also noticed that it veers right when I let the steering wheel go. Wobbling is not that bad, but I know my car well. What do you think?

Bernie!!

Comment: First step, check tire pressure, and check that no wheel weights have fallen off the wheels. If it looks ok visually, then maybe take it for a wheel alignment. This sounds like a classic alignment/balancing issue.